# what does "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" mean ? what should i do now?

Tags: javascript, alert

I just made 2 alert in my example.js file

**alert("test-javascript1");

alert("test-javascript2");**

nothing else in my file

and in my second alert box I got this message **prevent this page from creating additional dialogs**

my question is why this message appears in second alert box and what should i do? should i click on that check box?

prevent this page from creating additional dialogs java script

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" appears in the alert box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848381/why-prevent-this-page-from-creating-additional-dialogs-appears-in-the-alert-bo)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a browser thing to help users get rid of annoying sites. If you click on that, `alert`s will still be fired, but you won't see them (which is not what you need if you are the developer).

Answer (score 4):

The following steps show you how disable this Firefox feature:

1. Start Firefox, and type about:config in the url bar. Firefox will show the preferences screen. Please take care not to make changes at random.
2. Right click in the preferences area, and choose New > Integer from the popup menu.
3. In the dialog box that now appears, enter dom.successive_dialog_time_limit, followed by the value 0 (zero). Press OK.

When you return to the Promasys WebCRF, this message will no longer appear when opening the same dialog box more than once.

Comment: Is it possible to change it programatically?

Answer (score 2):

This alert has nothing to do with your code (apart from the fact that your `alert` calls triggered it), it's functionality found in some browsers to prevent "run-away" alerts (because they're modal).

Comment: Incidentally, if you're using `alert` to do basic Javascript debugging, you might want to consider something like `console.log` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this related answer: [Why "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" appears in the alert box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848381/why-prevent-this-page-from-creating-additional-dialogs-appears-in-the-alert-box/6624131#6624131)